# Is there any way to customize the Windows 7 snap feature?

Tags: windows-7

Is there any way to customize the Windows 7 snap feature so that I can make it do what I want it to do?

For example:

I run a dual monitor system, the windows snap feature doesn't recognize the area in between my monitors as a snap position, however, I can still snap windows to either end of my screens (and they will only take up half of that screen it was on). I want windows to recognize the area in between my monitors as valid snap locations and snap to that side of that screen, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no way to do this with the mouse, however you can use <kbd>Win</kbd>+ <kbd>Left or Right Arrow</kbd> to make the window snap to the side of your monitor.

Comment: Interesting, actually thats pretty useful, i guess for now that will suit my needs until i find some other software to do what want.

Comment: Actually, this seems to be the best for me. I can remap my controller to use these functions, speeds stuff up. Thanks!

Comment: WIN + UPARROW and WIN + DOWNARROW are also useful to get Window MAXIMIZE and Window MINIMIZE.

Comment: In addition to @Ryan Fisher if you press WIN + DOWNARROW once you bring the window down from MAXIMIZE and if you press the DOWNARROW a second time you minimize down to the task bar.

Answer (score 4):

There are third-party products that will let you farm out your desktop space with as much functionality as anyone would wish for.

One such product is [GridMove](http://jgpaiva.dcmembers.com/gridmove.html) :

> Freeware program GrideMove is a
>   windows management application that
>   lets you define grid templates on your
>   desktop into which you can quickly
>   snap your windows, with MultiMonitor Support.

In the forums, you can find many useful grid templates, for example [here](http://www.donationcoder.com/Forums/bb/index.php?topic=9387.0).

[image]

Comment: Yea, please tell me where i can take a look at some of these programs.

Answer (score 2):

I have only one monitor so I cannot confirm it will work, but [**PowerResizer**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/powerresizer/) looks interesting in improving the way AeroSnap works. Please give it a try and let us know...

[image]

Comment: Well, tried it out, it works good, it did what i asked for in my question. However, i cant find any way to customize it and it over rides the quick fullscreen change that the windows 7 snap comes standard with (which is something that i have been looking for since the days of xp). Works fine on duel screens though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keyboard shortcut windows key + an arrow key to snap windows to any direction/side even when using multiple monitors