# How do I get Browsers never to auto-expand to fill the screen in Win 7

Tags: windows-7, browser, window

I tend to take two browser windows (Chrome, Firefox, etc) and set them side-by-side. Often, if I'm dragging one toward the corner, Windows "helps" me by expanding it to cover the screen, which I then have to undo.

I've never once wanted this behavior and I'd *love* to disable it. Is it possible (either in Windows or in the individual browsers)?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/69067/98855 & http://superuser.com/questions/222597/how-to-disable-auto-maximize-resize-window-aero-snap-when-near-screen-edge?rq=1 Key search phrase 'Areo Snap"  There are other Q&As here also, if you use the search with that phrase.

Answer (score 2):

- Right click on you desktop and select Personalize.
- In the bottom left hand corner click Ease of Access Centre.
- Click on Make the mouse easier to use.
- Click the box "Prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the egde of the screen."

I hope this solves your problem

source:http://lifehacker.com/5799457/disable-windows-7s-aero-snap-from-the-control-panel

Comment: Seems to be just what I was looking for. Thanks!